# How to name URI part without parameters?

Tags: database, data-warehouse

What is an appropriate name for the URI part which is *before* the parameters part, I mean the full bolded part in the following example?

**foo://username:password@example.com:8042/over/there/index.dtb**?type=animal&name=narwhal#nose

I have a column in my database which contains such a part and I got stucked while finding *correct* name for this.

Answer (score 0):

That is the authority and the path.

There is no name for that part as a whole.

Comment: From your experience, would you suggest any name for such a column?

Comment: It depends.  What is it used for?

Comment: To indicate pages / subpages of a website, over which the webpage's users surf.

Comment: There are names for each part of the URI, I don't think there are any common names for subsets.

Answer (score -1):

Shouldn't that be?

> http://username:password@example.com:8042/over/there/index.dtb?type=animal&name=narwhal#nose

or https:// if you're using secured url

Comment: Well, I just provided my post with some foo example from wiki [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme].

Comment: The URI syntax consists of a URI scheme name (such as "http", "ftp", "mailto", "crid" or "file")